# Java: Load resources in two ways with strongly deviating time

Tags: java, jar, resources

When I load a PNG file from a JAR this way, it takes < 10 ms

```
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(FcAdminApp.class
            .getResource("/resources/focusAdmin.png")));
```

When I use this way it takes over 8000 ms!

```
    setIconImage(ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(
            FcAdminApp.class.getResource("/resources/focusAdmin.png"))));
```

Why this huge difference?

Comment: Using ImageIO usually doesn't have such a high load spike, we can't really tell for sure what's wrong without seeing the context first. Have you tried actually timing that piece of code, and seeing what exactly takes that long?

Comment: Yes. It's only the first use of ImageIO that takes so long. The second image takes <10ms

Comment: The first time it is possibly having to read and load the indexes of a large number of JAR files ... or even fetch some over a network connection.  On subsequent times, the files will have been fetched and the indexes will have been cached.